# Retrieving language name for keyboard layout from Win XP OS, using win API

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am developing an app using VC6 on WIn XP.
To retrieve default input language list from system GetKeyBoardLayoutList() and GetLocalInfo() APIs are used.

Follwoing is the code.

```
`UINT uLayouts; 
char szBuf[512];
HKL  *lpList = NULL;
uLayouts = GetKeyboardLayoutList(0, NULL);
lpList   = (HKL*)LocalAlloc(LPTR, (uLayouts * sizeof(HKL)));
uLayouts = GetKeyboardLayoutList(uLayouts, lpList);
for(UINT i = 0; i < uLayouts; i++)
{
    DWORD temp = (UINT)lpList[i] & 0xffffffff;
    GetLocaleInfo(MAKELCID(temp,SORT_DEFAULT), LOCALE_SLANGUAGE , szBuf, 512);
}`
```

In szBuf i am getting the input language name as "English (United States)" where as actaul name in OS is "English (United States) - US"

How can we get the exact name of input language present in the OS?
We tried using different flags as well like,

> LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE //English
>
> LOCALE_ILANGUAGE, LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, LOCALE_ICOUNTRY, LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME, LOCALE_SNATIVELANGNAME, LOCALE_SABBREVCTRYNAME, LOCALE_SNATIVECTRYNAME

however not able to fetch exact language name.

Comment: Where do you see your language as **"English (United States) - US"**? I do not see any keyboard layout with that name. I could see only **"English (United States)"**.

Comment: WinXP System: ControlPanel -> Regional & Lang Options -> Languages-> Text Services(Details Button) -> Settings -> Default Input Language box.
At above path we could see "English (United States) - US".

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
 LOCALE_IMEASURE // 0 = metric, 1 = US
```

Comment: How in the world does this answer the question? `LOCALE_IMEASURE` provides information about the measuring system used by a particular locale. It does not say anything about the "input language", which is what the question asks about.